# Do I have to query twice to get this result?

Tags: mysql, sql

New to SQL. I have 3 tables: `games`, `invitations`, and `users`

This query returns games that are in progress:

```
SELECT games.* 
FROM   games 
       INNER JOIN invitations 
               ON invitations.game_id = games.id 
                  AND invitations.user_id = 1 
                  AND invitations.status = 1 
                  AND games.status = 1;
```

This query returns games that are finished:

```
SELECT games.* 
FROM   games 
       INNER JOIN invitations 
               ON invitations.game_id = games.id 
                  AND invitations.user_id = 1 
                  AND invitations.status = 1 
                  AND games.status = 2;
```

This query returns games that the user has still not decided wether to join or not:

```
SELECT games.* 
FROM   games 
       INNER JOIN invitations 
               ON invitations.game_id = games.id 
                  AND invitations.user_id = 1 
                  AND invitations.status = 0;
```

I am wondering, if I have a web app that requires results from these 3 query, do I have to execute 3 sql statements or is there a way to compress them into 1? Making 3 requests seems like too much to me, is this normal way to deal with this?

Comment: how do you want the results to be, could it be a single collection or you need 3 different collections

Comment: @ArunPJohny Not sure what you mean by collections

Comment: if you need 3 different collection objects then you need to execute all the three queries, if you can handle the results in a single collection then you can use the below given answer

Comment: @ArunPJohny I see. I can deal with single collection, but the query given below doesn't work. There's an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
case when invitations.status = 1 
 then case 
        when games.status = 1 then 'progress'
        when games.status = 2 then 'finished'
      end
else 'not decided' end as game_status,
games.* 
FROM   games 
       INNER JOIN invitations 
               ON invitations.game_id = games.id 
                  AND invitations.user_id = 1 
                  AND (invitations.status = 0 or 
                        (invitations.status = 1 and games.status in (1,2)))
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1270b/1)

Comment: Missed the check on `games.status`

Comment: @PinnyM, I was in between editing code, yes i did miss that first time, thank you

Comment: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case when games.status = 1 then 'progress'
      when games.status = 2 then 'fin' at line 3'

Comment: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13'

Comment: @0xSina, try now, check sql fiddle

Comment: @rs thanks, works now. can you tell me what the syntax error was?

Comment: @0xSina, it was missing `)` at end

Answer (score 1):

You can condense it like this:

```
SELECT games.*, 
       CASE WHEN invitations.status = 1 THEN games.status 
            ELSE invitations.status 
       END status 
FROM   games 
   INNER JOIN invitations 
   ON invitations.game_id = games.id 
      AND invitations.user_id = 1 
      AND ((invitations.status = 1 AND games.status IN (1,2))
         OR (invitations.status = 0))
```

You can use the returned `status` column to determine which row is which.